# Populating Custom Fields from live JSON

Tags: custom-post-types, api, json

[image: JSON]

I'm trying to populate WP custom fields using the code below, my problem is I can't output the nested JSON field data.quote.USD. Can someone help find the right direction here? Thank you.

```
//some code here

        private function sanitize_remote_data($data_as_array)
        {
            foreach ($data_as_array as $inx => $data) {
                $data_as_array [$inx] = sanitize_text_field($data);
            }
            return $data_as_array;
        }

        private function parse_data($dirty_data_as_array)
        {
            $clean_data = $this->sanitize_remote_data($dirty_data_as_array);

            $this->raw = $clean_data;

            $this->CoinName = $this->raw ['name'];
            $this->CoinName = $this->raw ['name'];
            $this->Symbol = $this->raw ['symbol'];
            $this->Id = $this->raw ['id'];
            $this->Circ_Supply = $this->raw ['circulating_supply'];
            //$this->Price = $this->raw ['price'];

        }


    } // RemoteCoin
endif; // RemoteCoin


if (!class_exists('RemoteCoins')) :
    class RemoteCoins
    {
        public static $remote_data;

        public static $coins;

        private static function GetRemoteCoins($url)
        {
            $response = wp_remote_get($url);

            if (is_wp_error($response) || !isset($response['body'])) return; 

            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

            if (is_wp_error($body)) return; // bad body

            $data = json_decode($body, true);

            if (!$data || empty($data)) return; // bad data

            if (isset($data['page']) && isset($data['no_of_pages'])) {
                $page = $data['page'];
                $pages = $data['no_of_pages'];
                $next_page_link = $data['next_page_link'];
                if ($page !== $pages) {
                }
            }

            return $data;
        }

        public static function LoadRemoteCoins($to_create_posts)
        {
            self::$remote_data = self::GetRemoteCoins('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=5&sort=market_cap&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=***');



            if (!isset(self::$remote_data ['data'])) return; // no rows --- booo!


            $works = array();
            foreach (self::$remote_data ['data'] as $inx => $remote_item_data) {
                $coin = new RemoteCoin($remote_item_data);
                $works[] = $coin;
            }

            self::$coins = $works;

            if ($to_create_posts) {
                $count = 0;
                foreach (self::$coins as $inx => $coin) {
                    $count++; // for demo ---- let's not go overboard here

                    $post_id = self::CreateLocalCoinPost($coin);
if ($count >= 5) return self::$remote_data; 
                }
            }

            return self::$remote_data;
        }

//some code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by how the code relates, but here's how I would work with the data in the provided screenshot.

This is looping through the data array and accessing the quoted USD, if it exists.

I'm adding the prices to an array by the object's ID just to give you an example.

```
$prices = array();
foreach ( self::$remote_data['data'] as $data ) {
    if ( ! isset( $data->quote ) || ! isset( $data->quote->USD ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    $prices[ $data->id ] = $data->quote->USD->price;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Is there a way I can add that to the original foreach loop? Or is it necessary to create new one? `$works = array();
            foreach (self::$remote_data ['data'] as $inx => $remote_item_data) {
                // create coin instance
                $coin = new RemoteCoin($remote_item_data);
                $works[] = $coin;
            }`

Comment: This is the important part: `$data->quote->USD->price`.

Comment: Thank you. I found the root problem and it is on the sanitize_remote_data()